# Checking empty query parameter in nuxt

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, prismic.io

I have a search page on my Prismic/Nuxt project that makes a full-text query to the Prismic API.

This code will do that

```
export default {
  name: 'Search',
  async asyncData({ $prismic, params, query, error }) {
    try {
      // Query to get post content

      const products = await $prismic.api.query($prismic.predicates.fulltext('my.product.title', query.q), { orderings: '[my.product.title desc]' })
      // Returns data to be used in template
    
      return {
        products: products.results,
      }
    } catch (e) {    
      // Returns error page
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Page not found' })
    }
  },
}
```

The URL is `/search/?q=somesearch`

The problem is that if I hit /search/ with no query parameter it will immediately hit the catch with the error `Unable to encode undefined of type undefined`, obviously because it tries to query the API with an undefined value, but I can't seem to find out how to make a valid check to don't query the API if no query is set and instead just show the search box.

I have tried with

```
if query.q !== undefined
```

in the try section but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for an undefined value you can use:

`if (typeof query.q !== 'undefined')`

`typeof` returns the data type as a string, which makes checking for undefined values possible.